# How to upload file (pdf) using raw in Postman?

Tags: postman

I am trying to automate attaching a form data pdf file in Postman. Can it be done using raw in Postman? Please assist. Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Files can only be uploaded using the 'binary' and 'form-data' option. Postman considers raw data as a string.

Have a look at the documentation for a complete list of options Postman provides: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Is there anyway to get a file chosen during the Postman script run time? I found a solution running the script in command line, Newman. But I want to run the scripts in Postman itself.

Comment: You'd have to check the docs again. As far as I know, you need Newman

Comment: It really helped.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

You can choose the form-data upload. When adding a new form field, you can change the type of the field to "File". In Postman's current version (7.8) you have to leave the entry line and then move the mouse over the newly created entry to see this option.

[image]